# Bridged Wifi not working 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, tp-link

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 XFCE. I have successfully bridged a wifi network using tp link w740n. I did this in windows and it works without any problems. However, when I try to connect using ubuntu, it is unsuccessful. How am I to fix this?

Comment: When bridging did you select the `wlan0` device in the guest?

Comment: where is this option? i cant find it under ssid or bsid

Comment: Under network settings, when you select `bridges adatper`, there is a name field there you pick `wlan0` device!

Comment: i am using tplink w740n. I can not find any such options. There is Enable WDS Bridging which then gives an option of clicking survey

Comment: images would help in this case.